# Watson conversation reset conversation

Tags: watson-conversation

There is any way to tell to watson that he sould reset the conversation "after this point everty asked will be just like conversation_start"?

tks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Watson conversation is stateless. So it doesn't know anything about where you are in the conversation without the context object.

To reset the conversation, you just don't send the context object, and it will generate a new one.

Or let's say you are in a process flow, and want to reset to a particular point. Just take a copy of the context object at that point in time. Then use that to rollback.

This is assuming that your application layer hasn't done anything outside of conversation which would be related to the rollback.